# How to remove http://www.dalesearch.com from my PC

Tags: windows, search, virus, malware, adware

I am asking our community to get proven experience of how to remove "dalesearch" AdWare from my PC. 
I uninstalled it from applications, reset home page from browser, but it appear again as home page in my browser (FireFox) and there is nothing in add-ons> extensions or plugin, so that please help me if such experience exist.

Comment: Check to see if its edited the shortcut to your browser - some of them do that

Comment: and consider re-installing the browser

Comment: I am confused - it seems restart of my PC (after updates had been installed) fixed (committed fix of) problem.

Comment: If the updates and a restart fixed the problem, please post it as an answer and accept it. Any other input to this question will probably be speculation.

Comment: @Tog, OK (I'll do out in 2 days - SU limitations)
P.S. Any other input are welcome as useful info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I uninstalled it from Applications
- Resettled home page from browser options. 
  It helps only after PC was restarted (because of new installed Win. Updates)

Answer (score 2):

[AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) is a program that searches for and deletes Adware, Toolbars, Potentially Unwanted Programs (PUP), and browser Hijackers from your computer.  The types of programs that AdwCleaner targets are typically bundled with free programs that you download from the web.

I have used it to delete such annoyances in the past, where other programs have failed. It may help you in removing *dalesearch*.